# Load map Lon & Lat to script inside html is not working

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

the map lat & lon values from database to script and load to script is working correctly but the map is not showing

here  is the script

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var loc= document.getElementById('loc');

alert(loc.innerHTML);
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('+loc+');
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
mapTypeControl: false,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
if (geocoder) {
  geocoder.geocode( {  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            { 
              size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
            });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map, 
            title:address
        }); 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

      } else {

      }
    } else {

    }
  });
}
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 270px; height: 267px;">
</div>
```

the alert shows the value  10.52722212213278, 76.20814598432844

but the map is not load

if you knew about this please share answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace This

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng("Lat", "Long");
```

By

```
var loc= document.getElementById('loc'); //Remove This
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('+loc+'); //Remove This
```

Add Line With Two Seperate Cordinates i.e "Lat", "Long" as my code shows